# Not possible to download file using PHP's Microsoft Graph SDK

Tags: php, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have a service app and I'm willing to download a file from an user's Drive using [msgraph-sdk](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php)

I am able to upload a file using

```
$graph->createRequest("PUT", "/users/".$userId."/drive/items/root:/".$folderName."/".$fileName.":/content")
                ->upload($filePath);
```

But I am not able to download it. Here is the code I am using:

```
$graph = new Graph();
$graph->setAccessToken($accessToken);
$graph->createRequest("GET", "/users/".$userId."/drive/items/".$docId."/content")
                    ->download($filePath);
```

The error is: `PHP Warning:  fclose(): 16 is not a valid stream resource in microsoft-graph/src/Http/GraphRequest.php on line 344`

I could note that making a request to the URL `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{USER_ID}/drive/items/{DOC_ID}/content` using Postman and passing `Authorization Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}`, the response is the file's content, which is the expected behavior, but for some reason, calling it via PHP is not working.

Am I doing something wrong?

**---- UPDATE ----**

The problem seems to be related to the response I am getting after making the request. Documentation says that the [response code will be 302 and I need to redirect to the address in `Location` header](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_get_content#example), but it looks like that the `MS Graph` (or `Guzzle Client`) is not being capable to redirect to the address. I tried editing `GraphRequest.php` to enable it when creating a Client like this:

```
$clientSettings = [
    'base_uri' => $this->baseUrl,
    'verify' => false,
    'allow_redirects' => true,
    'headers' => $this->headers
];
$client = new Client($clientSettings);
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is a bug. I have logged it [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php/issues/67). There is a fix checked in and we are getting ready to publish a new version of the SDK, so you should be able to pull in the fix soon. In the meantime, you can incorporate the PR and verify that it solves the problem that you are seeing.